# Move Object in Circle using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, coordinate-transformation, opengl-compat

I have an object which i want to move around in a circle in Open GL/ Visual Studio. But so far, the object is only rotating around itself.

How can i make it move in a circular way?

Currently, it just translates the object instantly, but not over the course of my rotation animation.

This is my code in the display function - because i was told if you want the object not to rotate around itself, you need to translate. But so far, my object just ignores the translation here completely and still revolves around itself..

```
glRotatef(0.0f, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);   

drawExcavator(); // draws the object
```

And this is my animating function for later on to define the angle i use in the glRotatef call:

```
void animate() {

    // calculating the time needed for the animation 
    static long time = clock();
    long oldTime = time;
    float diffTime;
    time = clock();
    diffTime = ((float)(time - oldTime)) / ((float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // taken from the exercise sheets

    // checking if the animation has not been stopped:
    if (!pause) {
        angle += diffTime*rotateSpeed;
        elapsedTime += diffTime;
        frameCount++;

        // adding up the frames so that they are shown in the window:
        if (elapsedTime > 1.0)
        {
            // counting the fps so that they are outprinted in the window line:
            fps = (float)frameCount / elapsedTime;
            fps = fps / 100; // for correct frame numbers 
            elapsedTime = 0.0;
            frameCount = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to swap the translation and rotation operation:

```
glRotatef(angle, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);   
glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Explanation:

Translation: See the documentation of [**`glTranslate`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml):

> `glTranslate` produces a translation by `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by this translation matrix, with the product replacing the current matrix.

Rotation: See the documentation of [**`glRotate`**](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml):

> `glRotate` produces a rotation of angle degrees around the vector `x y z` . The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by a rotation matrix with the product replacing the current matrix.

The translation matrix looks like this:

```
Matrix4x4 translate;

translate[0] : ( 1,  0,  0,  0 )
translate[1] : ( 0,  1,  0,  0 )
translate[2] : ( 0,  0,  1,  0 )
translate[3] : ( tx, ty, tz, 1 )
```

And the rotation matrix around Y-Axis looks like this:

```
Matrix4x4  rotate;
float      angle;

rotate[0] : ( cos(angle),  0, sin(angle), 0 )
rotate[1] : ( 0,           1, 0,          0 )
rotate[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0, cos(angle), 0 )
rotate[3] : ( 0,           0, 0,          1 )
```

The result of `translate * rotate` is this:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),  0,  sin(angle), 0 )
model[1] : ( 0,           1,  0,          0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle), 0,  cos(angle), 0 )
model[3] : ( tx,          ty, tz,         1 )
```

[image]

The result of `rotate * translate` is:

```
model[0] : ( cos(angle),                     0,   sin(angle),                     0 )
model[1] : ( 0,                              1,   0,                              0 )
model[2] : ( -sin(angle),                    0,   cos(angle),                     0 )
model[3] : ( cos(angle)*tx - sin(angle)*tx,  ty,  sin(angle)*tz + cos(angle)*tz,  1 )
```

[image]

Comment: I did, and the explanation makes total sense. But it still, only revolves around itself.. :(

Comment: @Calimera What is the scale of your object? And what is the translation of 2.0 in relation to your object? use 20.0, 200.0 .... istead of 2.0, for debug reasons.

Comment: Aaaah ok i was SO stupid!! i changed up the size and it now is visible that it drives in a circle. It still rotates around the origin but in a much bigger circle, it looks much better - that it still rotates around the middle thats normal isnt it ? :)

Comment: @Calimera Yes, But you can can shift the rotation axis by another `glTranslatef` operation before the `glRotatef(); glTranslatef();`. That would be a combination of the two possibilities, which I explained in my answer.